Getting advertisment id error even though my app is completely ad-free

Hello everyone, While updating my app, I got this error(image) in console. My app is completely ad-free but still it is asking me to enable ad_id. I am not even using ad_id permission in menifest file of my app.
Can you please explain why I am getting this error.

Could one of your dependencies declare this in this manifest file? Do you declare it?

after searching on internet, I found that cause that the firebase analytics uses ad_Id.

If no Ads in the App:
To remove the AD_ID permission, add tools:node="remove" in your AndroidManifest.xml:
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove"/>

Ensure this namespace declaration is at the top of your manifest:
<manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" ... />

This ensures the permission is excluded from the final manifest, even if third-party libraries request it. More details are available in this answer.
If Ads are in the App:
Add the following permission to your AndroidManifest.xml before the  tag:
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>

Google docs: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient.Info#public-methods
